# Output Mysql Result in Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am getting input as array like the variable declared in **$array**

I need to get my mysql result as array,

My input is like

```
$array = array('5', '4', '21', '55', '97', '17');


$pid = implode(",", $array);

using pid i am processing the query

**while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
}**
```

How i want is like

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);
```

What can i do for this ?

Comment: use `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` instead of `mysql_fetch_array($result)`

Answer (score 0):

Well You want your customize array separately..
Then following code can be useful to achieve that-

```
$array =array();
**while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
array_push($array, "foo", "bar");
}**
```

and here you can put your value to $array one by one depending on the key and value of `$row`.